# Postgres SIMILAR TO with AND

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching

Is there a way that I can change this OR expression to AND?

```
title SIMILAR TO '%(foo|bar)%'
```

This now returns all rows that include either foo or bar in title. How would I return rows that include foo and bar but not necessary in this order.

So "foo bar" and "bar foo" and "foo bla bar" are all valid results. But "foo salad" isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simple `like` with `all(array[...])`:

```
with the_data(title) as (
values 
    ('foo bar'),
    ('bar foo'),
    ('foo bla bar'),
    ('foo salad')
)
select *
from the_data
where title like all(array['%foo%', '%bar%']);

    title    
-------------
 foo bar
 bar foo
 foo bla bar
(3 rows)
```

Update in response to a comment. The case where you are searching only for whole words is a bit more complicated. You should use [`regex_split_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) and check if the resulting array contains an array of searched words (using [array operator @>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)):

```
with the_data(title) as (
values 
    ('Foo bar'),
    ('Bar foo'),
    ('foo bla bar'),
    ('foo salad'),
    ('foobar'),
    ('barfoo')
)
select *
from the_data
where regexp_split_to_array(lower(title), ' ') @> array['foo', 'bar'];

    title    
-------------
 Foo bar
 Bar foo
 foo bla bar
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Yup this works. Do you maybe know how to ignore the case with this. So for example foo and Foo and FOO is the same

Comment: @StevenSeagull `ILIKE` is the case `I`nsensitive `LIKE`

Comment: @StevenSeagull Do not forget to [`create index idx_the_data_title on the_data using gist(title gist_trgm_ops);`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) to make your searches faster.

Comment: @klin I just noticed that this solution also returns:

searched word = "test"

It also returns "greatest" and "latest" is there a way that I could only use this for full words? So only "test" is the right response

Answer (score 3):

you can do this :

```
 title SIMILAR TO '%(foo%bar|bar%foo)%'
```

Comment: Yeah but this is not elegant since I would have to generate all possible variations of multiple words.